# Cannot SSH into server because authorized_keys is in a different folder

Tags: ssh, authentication, sshd, key-authentication

I was able to SSH into this remote server using password authentication before. I wanted to change that to make it use private/public key pairs instead. I followed the necessary steps by generating a key pair, editing the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to enable RSA and Pubkey authentication, and disable password authentication:

`RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes 
PasswordAuthentication no`

The problem is that I (mistakenly) moved the `authorized_keys` file out of the `~/.ssh/` folder in the remote host. Therefore, after exiting the remote host I can't SSH back in as it doesn't recognize my private key, giving me the following message:
`Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`

Am I permanently locked out of the remote server now? Is there a way to specify the location of the `authorized_keys` file in the SSH command itself?

Comment: As a side note, there is (probably) no point in enabling `RSAAuthentication yes`.  That only applies to ssh v1, which is long deprecated.  If your `sshd_config` includes `Protocol 2` rather than `Protocol 2,1` or `Protocol 1.2`, you are not allowing ssh v1 anyway.

Comment: I see, that explains why `RSAAuthentication` wasn't in `sshd_config` in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot specify an alternate location from your end of the connection. This is intentional and part of the security of ssh. The ssh server will not use certain files even when in the correct location if they have the wrong file permissions (i.e. `~/.ssh` and many of the files that are stored therein.)

If you removed password authentication and restarted the ssh daemon/service, you will need to fix the problem with the authorized_keys file on the server locally, or change the configuration options back to allow password authentication and restart sshd.

Comment: But how do I allow back password authentication, or fix the problem with authorized_keys, if I cannot ssh into the server in the first place?

Comment: You will need to access the the server on the local console, or use another remote access method if available. This is a common pitfall for users learning to manage SSH; it's considered a 'right of passage' by some.

Comment: What I suggest is you allow password authentication and test with ssh-keys until you are satisfied they work without problem; then turn off password authentication.

Comment: That's what's on my mind, but I can't figure out how to get in the remote server without the keys working and with the password authentication disabled.

Comment: Your first problem is accessing the physical server and changing the ssd_config changing it back to `PasswordAuthentication yes` and restarting the service. Once that is done and you can remotely ssh again, then you can fix the authorized_keys location and any other issues, verify the key works, etc. Once you know the ssh key works, THEN you can attempt to turn off password auth again.

Comment: I don't have access to the physical server, so I'll have to ask the administrator to do it from their end I suppose.